# Can I apply changes from a perforce patch(downloaded from review board) to my code

Tags: perforce, patch, review-board

A colleague has created a perforce change list and has posted a review on review board for the change. Alas the change is not shelved, but I need to apply the change to my code. The colleague will not be available for some days so I can not ask him to shelve the files or to give me a unified diff of the files. So all I have now is the code review. From reviewboard I can download the perforce patch for the change. Please note this is not unified diff(like the output of p4 diff -du), but is some other format. Now my question is  - is there a way I can apply this patch to another perforce client? Or maybe to convert the diff to unified diff so that I can use linux `patch` command?

Comment: Depending on the size of the patch, you can always use your text editor. The patch file lists the lines to be inserted and deleted, and the line numbers in the file where the changes are to be made., so you can perform those inserts and deletes yourself, by cutting-and-pasting from the patch file into the modified file in your editor.

Comment: I can also use the review for that. This is the only option I found so far.  However the change is quite big so I wanted to find an alternative if possible

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straightforward to apply a patch file downloaded from reviewboard on to a copy of the source code.

The only thing that you need to change is the path to the source code.

So, for example, given a downloaded patch file which has lines like:

```
Index:getasset/env/getasset.global.settings.env
===================================================================
---  //grand/ats/main/getasset/env/getasset.global.settings.env //grand/ats/main/getasset/env/getasset.global.settings.env3#24
+++  //grand/ats/main/getasset/env/getasset.global.settings.env   (working copy)
@@ -59,5 +59,13 @@
```

You only need to change each line starting with `+++`.

You can either change it to an absolute path to your source code or a relative path from some starting dir.

Then you combine that with judicious use of `-p` and potentially `-d` and the patch file will apply.